# Data scraping a dynamic page and building a bell curve model

Tags: r, rvest

There are a few layers to my question so please bear with me:

1. I'm trying to scrape data from a dynamic web page. [This is the page](http://www.forexfactory.com/#tradesPositions)

I'm attempting to scrape the number of traders that are long or short each currency pair. As shown in the below picture:

[image]

Now, I need the number of traders - not the percentages.

2. Here is what I have done:

   ```
   # Load rvest package
   library(rvest)

   # Forex Factory

   # EURUSD
   # Read the url
   eurusd <- read_html("http://www.forexfactory.com/#tradesPositions-sort=instruments&tradesPositions-sortOrder=asc&tradesPositions-details=0")

   #Set up the nodes for EURUSD
   #FF stands for 'Forex Factory'
   FFeurusd<-eurusd%>%html_nodes(".label")%>%html_text()

   #Scrape HTML page into a dataframe
   shorteurusd_table<-data.frame(FFeurusd[1])
   longeurusd_table<-data.frame(FFeurusd[2])

   #This is where I attempt to merge the results from long and short traders and clean up the results (doesn't really work)
   shorteurusd_table$FFeurusd.1.<-gsub("%","",shorteurusd_table$FFeurusd.1.)

   #Adjust attributes of table
   final<-merge(shorteurusd_table,longeurusd_table)
   colnames(final) <-c("Short","Long")
   rownames(final) <-c("EURUSD")
   ```

This is the output from the above code.

Problem: I only want the number in each column, i.e. 263 and 315.

[image]

---

I'm aware this is a highly inefficient way of setting up a data frame but I have limited experience in R.

I can't even get the other currency pairs to work because I can't get an accurate path. If I copy paste in the XPath, it never works.

I also want to be able to calculate the ratio between long and short - store that data, normalise the scores and model a distribution. So that one could compare the current ratio to historical data. Eventually I need to put the code on a server, scrape the info a few times a day so its automated. I understand that last task is considerable but that's the task I've set myself.

I'm confident with R when doing mathematical modeling and statistics - so Ill probably be okay once the data scraper is actually running and storing those data points. **Sorry for text wall - it required detailed explanation.**

Thanks

Comment: just explode it on space and take the one you require.

Comment: A bit of what @AammadUllah said: `data_list <- lapply(strsplit(FFeurusd, split = " "), as.numeric); sapply(data_list, FUN = function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the start.

Please do the data cleaning and you will get plenty of help online.

```
url<-"http://www.forexfactory.com/?flexId=flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1&more=1" 
pgsession<-html_session(url) 
for(i in 1:10){   
if(i == 1){
        table<-html_table(html_nodes(read_html(pgsession), xpath=paste0('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[',i,']/table')), fill= TRUE)[[1]]   
}else{
        table<-rbind(t,html_table(html_nodes(read_html(pgsession), xpath=paste0('//*[@id="flexBox_flex_trades/positions_tradesPositionsCopy1"]/div[',i,']/table')), fill= TRUE)[[1]])   
} 
}
```

Comment: Would you recommend any documentation for me to learn how to do the data cleanup?